# SQLAlchemy 'module' not callable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, guid

I am using the SQlAlchemy recommended uuid() support add-on as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type). However, when I use it in my SQLAlchemy code, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Referring to the module, GUID.

Here is the GUID code, taken directly from the source:

**GUID.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
  """Platform-independent GUID type.

  Uses Postgresql's UUID type, otherwise uses
  CHAR(32), storing as stringified hex values.

  """
  impl = CHAR

  def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
    if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
      return dialect.type_descriptor(UUID())
    else:
      return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

  def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
    if value is None:
      return value
    elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
      return str(value)
    else:
      if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
        return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value)
      else:
        # hexstring
        return "%.32x" % value

  def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
    if value is None:
      return value
    else:
      return uuid.UUID(value)
```

And here is my model which calls it

**user.py**

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime
from app.custom_db import GUID

class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(GUID(), primary_key=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(80))
  password = db.Column(db.String(80))
  datejoined = db.Column(db.DateTime,default = db.func.now())

  def __init__(self, name, email, password):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.password = password

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.name
```

Any idea why I can't create this `uuid()` PKey?

---

Here's the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    from app import app                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/achumbley/Pile/app/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                           
    from models import user                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/achumbley/Pile/app/models/user.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                         
    class User(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/home/achumbley/Pile/app/models/user.py", line 7, in User                                                                                                                                                                             
    id = db.Column(GUID(), primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What does `app/custom_db.py` look like? You are importing GUID from that file, so my guess is that that file is importing GUID incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is GUID.py, and you're importing it like `from app.custom_db import GUID` (as you have it), then what you've really imported is the file, not the class. To get to the class, you would need to call `GUID.GUID()`.

Alternatively, you could import the class by importing it as:

```
from app.custom_db.GUID import GUID
```

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you